# Combining Arrays and adding scores

Tags: php, arrays

I have to associated arrays that are generated from 2 search engines that return the following

Bing:

```
Array ( [cars.com/] => Array ( [score] => 100 )
        [car.com/] => Array ( [score] => 99 )
        [car.org/] => Array ( [score] => 98 ).....
```

Google:

```
Array ( [hertz.com/] => Array ( [score] => 100 )
        [edmunds.com/] => Array ( [score] => 99 )
        [thrifty.com/] => Array ( [score] => 98 )....
```

I want to create a ranked combined array, the bing array is the rank, I then want to add the Google array, if a google url array matches a url in the Bing array I want to add the scores, if a url does not match then I just want to insert it into the array.

Any ideas how I would go about implementing this.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$combined = array(); 

foreach($bing as $key=>$value){ // for each bing item
    if(isset($combined[$key]))
        $combined[$key] += $value['score']; // add the score if already exists in $combined
    else
        $combined[$key] = $value['score']; // set initial score if new
}

// do the same for google
foreach($google as $key=>$value){
    if(isset($combined[$key]))
        $combined[$key] += $value['score'];
    else
        $combined[$key] = $value['score'];
}

print_r($combined); // print results
```

You can use a function instead of duplicating the code.. will be best if you have more search engines to analyze.

Comment: I'm getting "Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in" for  $combined += $value['score'];

Answer (score 0):

Actually it would be interesting to benchmark how creating combined array performs against manipulating array in place.

```
foreach ($google as $k=>$v){
    if(isset($google[$k]) $bing[$k]['score'] += $v['score'];
        else $bing[$k] = $v;
```